# Запятая после придаточного предложения в СПП

Tags: пунктуация, спп

SOS! Где здесь закрывается придаточное предложение? В каком месте нужно (и нужно ли?!) ставить запятую?

О том, как сэкономить и увеличить ресурс ТПА с большим Ду, как увеличить ресурс резиновых уплотнительных элементов, как сделать экологически чистыми процессы нанесения антикоррозийных покрытий, как получать правильные межфланцевые прокладки большего диаметра и еще удешевить их производство и о других инновациях нашего предприятия я постараюсь рассказать в следующих номерах журнала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О том,( как сэкономить и увеличить ресурс ТПА с большим Ду),  (как увеличить ресурс резиновых уплотнительных элементов),  ( как сделать экологически чистыми процессы нанесения антикоррозийных покрытий),        (как получать правильные межфланцевые прокладки большего диаметра и еще удешевить их производство),    и о других инновациях нашего предприятия я постараюсь рассказать в следующих номерах журнала. Сложноподчинённое предложение с 4 придаточными, соединёнными однородным подчинением.

О том, как..., как..., как..., **как...,** и о других инновациях я постараюсь рассказать в следующих номерах журнала.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Поняла. Я сначала тоже так подумала, а потом начала сомневаться...